# How to handle external and internal event in j2me

Tags: java-me

i am developing game in j2me. In that i have to handle external and internal event.. I studied in some of websites that we can handle the event with the help of `hidenotify()` and `shownotify()`.

But it dont know where to use these two methods? whether in `hidenotify()` in `pauseApp()` and `shownotify()` in `startApp()` or somewhere else..

Please anyone give me a clear idea about handling the event in mobile.

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by external and internal events

Answer (score 1):

In J2ME world, external events resemble the following:

1. In coming SMS message. This is used trigger application specific action caused by a message sent from a pre-defined and well known sender. This feature is known as "push".
2. Media card inserted and the application needs to recognize it and act upon it.
3. If the phone is NFC enabled, launching an application when the phone is taken to a card reader.
4. When a server is attempting to connect to the phone, launch the application and perform some specific action. This requires that phone is addressable on network; very few of them support it.
5. Launching the application at a specific time.

I hope you get the idea. Most of the above are achieved by making use Push Registry.

The events that you are talking about are the callbacks to application that AMS (Application Management Software) notifies before the component is being shown and before the component is being hidden.

And pauseApp will be called by AMS when the application is about to be paused; this typically happens when there is an incoming phone call, or the flip is closed (on a flip phone) etc.

Hope it answers your question.